# Deep clone Doctrine entity with related entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have created an entity `A` with `OneToMany` relation to `B`, which have relation `OneToMany` to `C`.

I have to clone this `A` entity and set it in database with new id. Also all deep relations should be cloned with new ids too.

What have I tried is to set `A` id to `null`:

```
$A = clone $A_original;
$A->setId(null);
$em->persist($A);
```

It creates new record in `A` table, but does not in `B` and `C`.

What should I do to make a full copy of `A` entity ?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You have to implement a `__clone()` method in your entities that sets the id to null and clones the relations if desired. Because if you keep the id in the related object it assumes that your new entity `A` has a relation to the existing entities `B` and `C`.

Clone-method for `A`:

```php
public function __clone() {
    if ($this->id) {
        $this->setId(null);
        $this->B = clone $this->B;
        $this->C = clone $this->C;
    }
}
```

Clone-method for `B` and `C`:

```php
public function __clone() {
    if ($this->id) {
        $this->setId(null);
    }
}
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/doctrine-user/Nu2rayrDkgQ

https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html

Based on the comment of coder4show a clone-method for a OneToMany relationship on `A` where `$this->M` is OneToMany and therefore an `ArrayCollection`:

```php
public function __clone() {
    if ($this->id) {
        $this->setId(null);

        // cloning the relation M which is a OneToMany
        $mClone = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($this->M as $item) {
            $itemClone = clone $item;
            $itemClone->setA($this);
            $mClone->add($itemClone);
        }
        $this->M = $mClone;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is, it doesn't seem to work on OneToMany, any ideas why?

Comment: @coder4show that is because you are cloning the `ArrayCollection` and not the elements in it. I have added a clone method for a OneToMany relationship.

Comment: In this example the OneToMany relationship will not be cloned correctly, as the cloned related entities still refer to the old entity. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28313673/3215645) for a working example

Comment: @Richard thank you, you are right. I have updated the example to make it work.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `$this->setId(null)` rather than `$this->id = null` ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY If you have a setter I would recommend using it because there might be some other logic in it that should be triggered when changing the id. Other than that I see no particular reason to use the setter. For cloning it should have the same effect.

Comment: Yes this is the aim of accessors, but we don't often see them used from the owner entities (`$this`). For example you are setting `$this->M` directly here.

Comment: Another  synthax to clone a collection `$this->M = $this->M->map(function ($item) { return (clone $item)->setA($this);} `

Answer (score 9):

There is also a module that will do this called DeepCopy:

https://github.com/myclabs/DeepCopy

```
$deepCopy = new DeepCopy();
$myCopy   = $deepCopy->copy($myObject);
```

You can also add filters to customize the copy process.

Comment: Hi @Ben can you take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650001/clone-entity-in-cascade-mode?noredirect=1#comment45641837_28650001)

Comment: I have found this incredibly buggy and its faster to just roll your own `clone` methods

Answer (score 3):

I wasnt able to use DeepClone (it require php 7.1+), so I founded more simple way to clone relations in entity __clone method

```
$this->tags = new ArrayCollection($this->tags->toArray());
```

Comment: Perfect ! It works. I'm using iterable so it looks like : `$this->foos = \iterable_to_array($this->foos);`

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to clone a ArrayCollection:

```php
$this->setItems(
    $this->getItems()->map(function (Item $item) {
        return clone $item;
    })
);
```