# Assigning cloned object in SonataAdmin class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I want to create Game object with cloned Scenario object.

```
Create Game form:
    Name: My game
    Scenario: MyScenario (Combo box)
```

Basing on answer for [Deep clone Doctrine entity with related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158111/deep-clone-doctrine-entity-with-related-entities) question I have implemented `__clone` methods.

I'm using `__clone` method in `prePersist` method in `GameAdmin` class.

```
public function prePersist($game)
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $game->setAuthor($user);
    $cp = clone $game->getScenario(); //Error after add this
    $game->setScenario($cp);          //two lines
}
```

I'm not sure is this a proper place for doing this operation because I'm getting `MappingException`:

```
The class 'Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\ManyToManyPersister' was not found in the chain 
configured namespaces Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Entity, 
Sonata\UserBundle\Entity, Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity, 
Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity, GM\AppBundle\Entity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Scenario` entity I have `$tasks` which is `ArrayCollection`. I was cloning entire collection and that cause problems.

Cloning each `task` in loop solves problem:

```
public function __clone()
{
    if($this->id)
    {
        $this->setId(null);
        $ta = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach($this->tasks as $task)
        {
            $ta[] = clone $task;
        }
        $this->tasks = $ta;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting your solution! Helped me out. :)