# Symfony - unset the id and persist it again

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am writing a duplicate action within **Symfony** and **Doctrine**..

What I want to accomplish is to just *load* the object, *unset* the `id` and *persist* it again.

I was thinking of an example:

```
$A = $em->find('Some\Entity',1);
$B = clone $A;
$B->setId(null);
```

Is this the right way to do that?

Idea is to have an `/duplicate` endpoint which will implement this logic. I saw that using _`_clone()` in the entity class would be the best way to go, but is there any workaround for my case?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158111/deep-clone-doctrine-entity-with-related-entities) might help you..

Comment: I updated my post.  Can you please take a look? Thanks @Bossman

Comment: So, if you create a `__clone` method in your entity that sets the `id` as null (This gets invoked when you use `clone`). Then in your `/duplicate` endpoint do what you are doing `$new = clone $A` and persist as normal, it should add as a new entity with a new *id*.

Comment: I think you can use the detach method from doctrine too